# How to wrap text in Button and change Button color on click in Google App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

Haven't coded in years, and started to play around with Google App Maker last week. As the title suggests, I have a couple questions.

1. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to dynamically change the color of a button upon click. Right now I have the button changing enabled status to false on click, and using CSS style to change the color of disabled buttons to gray. Is there a way to do this without disabling the button?
2. Is there a way to wrap text in a button? Right now I am overlaying a Label on the button with the correctly styled font, but would ideally like to have that text be from the Button, as the space the label takes up is not clickable.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

add some lines to your page or global styles this
this should let you wrap text.

```
.app-Button {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Say you want to change your button blue when a Boolean value gets changed to "true" in your data source.

add a class to your styles

```
.blue{
  background: blue;
}
```

then select your button and in the property editor>Display>styles click the drop down and select binding

set the binding to

```
=@datasource.item.**YourBooleanItem** === true? ['blue']:[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Clarification there are two steps

1. Define a CSS class
2. Add the Class to the "styles" property of
   your widget.

The Answer above uses a "binding" but also means that you've got to have an Item with this binding which you may not want.

I wanted a 'decimal' button to be orange when it was active.  So on the Page I created a DecimalActive property.  I used the onAttach event to set this property to false.

I created a CSS Class (local to the page) named Orange and Normal
.Orange {background:orange};
.Normal {background:white};

Then the following is my onClick

```
onClick(widget,event)
{
     widget.root.properties.DecimalActive = !widget.root.properties.DecimalActive;
     widget.styles = widget.root.properties.DecimalActive ? ['Orange'] : ['White'];
}
```

The challenge was figuring out exactly what AppMaker wanted in the styles [].  I don't think it puts applied styles in this array.  At least they didn't show up when I console.log(JSON.stringify(widget.styles);

I have verified that this does work (Dec 2019)
I think this answer is clearer and if someone wants to bind it the color change they still can.